# Mode-local keybindings in ViM?

Tags: vim

I've recently return to ViM, after several years in Emacs, and something I'm missing is the ability to set filetype-local keybindings:  e.g. I want to make _ underline the current word in Markdown-type files, but do something completely different in, say, Python.  Is there a way to do this other than just autocmds that override each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map <buffer> ...` to make a mapping local to a buffer rather than global.  Then set up an autocommand to load that mapping only for certain filetypes, or put the mapping into a ftplugin file for that filetype.  Luckily, local mappings aren't cleared when a buffer is hidden, only when a buffer is destroyed, so the mappings will stick around as you switch between buffers.

See `:h :map-local`.